# Tkinter Toplevel window and multiple workspaces - place window in originating linux workspace

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I run this on Debian Gnome, but I think this is relevant for most UNIX distributions and interfaces:

```
from time    import sleep
from Tkinter import Tk,Toplevel
tk=Tk()
def run():
    sleep(3)
    Toplevel(tk)
run()
```

In Gnome, running this and switching a workspace will cause the Toplevel window to appear in your current workspace, instead of the one that actually runs the command. Is there a way to fix this so the new window appears where the command runs? If this is a Gnome specific thing let me know and I'll amend the question and tags.

**To be clear**: I have an app that can pop these windows up on it's own while working - and I'm doing other things. The sleep in the above is there to emulate that.

This makes sense it would work this way, but I'm wondering if there is any easy bypass? I have an application using Toplevels as "patience, running" windows, and it's annoying when they appear in different workspaces.